# Schedule a Meeting In Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have to schedule a meeting through my sharepoint teamsite. Requirements are

1. Adding people to the meeting
2. Sending email invitation to all intended people for meeting
3. Booking an available conference area in our company. (List of conference areas are displayed in a dropdown box)

If the selected conference area is not available then appropriate message should be displayed. So how to add validation here?

Is there any out of the box feature available to meet the above requirements. I am new to SharePoint. Please help